# r raster cumulative sum calculation according to pre-defined time steps

Tags: r, time-series, r-raster, cumulative-sum

I have a time series of 10 daily raster data and I need to calculate the -5 to +5 time steps cumulative sums according to the pixel values (=time 0) of a reference raster.

I am able to calculate the yearly cumulative sum (here below called ‘sum_YY’)

step1 create the 10 daily raster timeseries

```
require(raster)
idx <- seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), as.Date("2011/12/31"), '10 days')
r <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5)
s <- stack(lapply(1:length(idx), function(x) setValues(r, values = sample(x = c(-5:5),size = ncell(r), replace = T))))
s <- setZ(s, idx)
```

step 2 calculate the cumulative sum by year

```
Y <- unique(format(as.Date(getZ(s), format = "X%Y.%m.%d"), format = "%Y"))
sum_YY <- stack()
for (i in Y) {
  dates <- format(getZ(s), "%Y") == i
  t <- calc(subset(s, which(dates)), cumsum)
  sum_YY <- stack(sum_YY,t)
}
```

But this is not the output I am looking for. 
I need to use cumsum according to the reference raster 'refer'.

step 3 create the reference raster

```
refer <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5)
refer <- setValues(refer,sample(x = c(15:25),size = ncell(refer), replace = T))
```

The ‘refer’ raster pixel values indicate the timestep ‘X’ and I want to calculate the cumulative sums from the ‘s stack’ timesteps X-5 to X+5 for each of the years

i.e. if ‘refer’ pixel value X = 20 I need to calculate the cumulative sums from the ‘s stack’ layers from 15 to 25 for each of the years. The same approach for the other pixels in 'refer'

I have no idea how to introduce the reference raster in the calculation, any help??

Thanks a million!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a clean approach. But here is one way to do it:

```
rs <- stack(refer, s)
a <- calc(rs, fun=function(x) sum(x[(x[1]-4):(x[1]+6)]))
```

StackSelect was designed for problems like this, but I now realize that it needs more flexibility. It would be nice to be able to select multiple layers at once, and to apply a function. But you could do this (probably inefficient)

```
x <- calc(refer, function(x) (x-5):(x+5), forceapply=T)
y <- stackSelect(s, x)
z <- sum(y)
```